# Storing complex data model in cloud firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I know this is a dumb question, but please help out.

I have three model classes

**Student class**

```
public class Student {
    private String department;
    private String year;
    private String division;
    private String batch;
    private Timetable timetable;

    public Student() {}

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getDivision() {
        return division;
    }

    public void setDivision(String division) {
        this.division = division;
    }

    public String getBatch() {
        return batch;
    }

    public void setBatch(String batch) {
        this.batch = batch;
    }

    public Timetable getTimetable() {
        return timetable;
    }

    public void setTimetable(Timetable timetable) {
        this.timetable = timetable;
    }
}
```

**Timetable class**

```
public class Timetable implements Parcelable {
    private String day;
    private List<Lecture> lectures;

    public Timetable(String day, List<Lecture> lectures) {
        this.day = day;
        this.lectures = lectures;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public List<Lecture> getLectures() {
        return lectures;
    }

    public void setLectures(List<Lecture> lectures) {
        this.lectures = lectures;
    }
}
```

**Lecture class**

```
public class Lecture implements Parcelable {
    private String code;
    private String professorCode;
    private String room;
    private long startTime;
    private long endTime;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getProfessorCode() {
        return professorCode;
    }

    public void setProfessorCode(String professorCode) {
        this.professorCode = professorCode;
    }

    public String getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void setRoom(String room) {
        this.room = room;
    }

    public long getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(long startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public long getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(long endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

}
```

Now at this point because there is a nested containment in my data model, I am stuck in how I should structure my data in Firebase Cloud Firestore.

> **Student** have department, year, division, Timetable. 
>   **Timetable** has day and list of Lectures. 
>   **Lecture** have code, professorCode, room, startTime, endTime

It'll be really great if someone helps to structure this data in firestore in terms of **collection and documents**. I am new to Firestore and I am finding collections and documents difficult.
I could have used Realtime Database, but there are some issues so I have to use Firestore only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could have 3 JSONs for every entity (Student, Timetable, Lecture), but instead of having Timetable in Student, you can store Timetable ID in Student. And list of Lectures would be `HashMap<String, Boolean>`, where key is Lecture ID, since [that's the way of storing arrays in firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays). You can also read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data)

Comment: @StefanGolubović thanks for the reply. But I am specifically looking to store data in cloud firestore, and not realtime database. I can't use JSON in firestore. Can you just show me how you would store this model in Firestore? Like in terms of documents and collection.. Thanx

Comment: I visualized it like JSON, but the idea is the same. Instead of having nested data, you could store IDs of things you need.

Comment: @StefanGolubović Oh I think I am getting an idea. Thank you so much. Still if you don't mind,  can you explain this nested data in terms of documents and collections?

Comment: @StefanGolubović Like what data should be stored in document or collection and vice verca. Like in terms of Firestore collectiona and doucments

Comment: In your case, you would have 3 collections called Students, Timetables and Lectures. Each collection contains documents of that kind. Documents of type Student contain department, year, division and ID/name of Timetable document. Timetable documents contain day and list of Lecture IDs/names, that can be (or should be) represented as map (HashMap). Lecture documents contain code, professorCode, room, startTme and endTime. This would be organization with [root-level collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data#root_level_collections).

Comment: @StefanGolubović Thank you so much sir!

Comment: You say: "I am stuck in how I should structure my data". Ok but you want to structure your data to do what? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @AlexMamo Hello sir. Actually I am making a timetable app which displays a student's timetable by asking him for his department, year and division. Once that is done, the app searches for the related "timetable" on firestore which has a day of the week and a list of Lectures. Now after I have this list of lectures, I just want to show this list of lectures when the student enters the above mentioned details(department, year, division). I am finding difficulties on how I structure the Student, Timetable and Lecture models in firestore. The details should fetch the corrosponding timetable. Thanx

Comment: @AlexMamo Please note that a "timetable" may be different for different students depending on the details entered by the student.